# How feasible is armor composed of micarta?

Tags: armors

I'm using Micarta as a catchall for fabric and resin composites. Given the strength of Spider silk, and the potential ease of fabrication of micarta, could micarta spider silk armor function as a bulletproof vestment

Answer (score 3):

### Micarta Armor is a Thing

Fibreglass/resin composites are used in certain Light Armor vehicles in place of steel ballistic plate backing to reduce weight.

[According to this](https://www.agy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Composite_Armor_Solutions_Stanag_4569-Technical.pdf), unfaced composite panels can stop standard non-armor piercing assault rifle rounds like 7.62mmx51 M80 and 5.56mmx45 M193, but armor piercing rounds like the 7.62mmx51 M2AP require a ceramic facing to be effective.

Class IV body armor generally gives a level of protection comparable to somewhere between threat level 1-2 vehicular armor.  So, the 16mm thick and 46.6 kg/m^2 armor used in vehicles would be at the very high-end of what you would expect out of body armor.  Translated into a 12x10" plate this would weigh about 7.95lb.  [According to this](https://aimingexpert.com/how-much-does-a-bulletproof-vest-weigh/), most class IV ballistic plates weigh 6-8lb per 10x12" plate; so, yes it would make a viable material to use in body armor.

### But Spider silk, is not Ideal.

Despite its high resistance to being torn, spider silk stretches much more easily than many other fibres.  This makes it a bad reinforcer for a rigid resin or resin like material because it would stretch allowing the resin to fracture.  Instead, you want to use a fibre that resists stretching as much as possible such as fibreglass or carbon fibre.

Spidersilk is a better candidate for being paired with shear activated liquid polymers than being adhesively hardened into a micarta plate.  Generally speaking, flexible armors including those made from spidersilk or kevlar (with or without shear activated polymers) do not exceed Class III meaning that it's good for stopping most calibers of civilian owned weapons like handguns, shotguns, and varmint rifles, but not good against most military grade weapons like assault rifles or LMGs.

Answer (score 2):

## Definitely

It really depends on what kind of weapon you're trying to stop and how mobile you need to be. The photo below from Wikipedia shows micarta insulation in a canister support. It looks like those pieces are about one inch thick. An inch of micarta should stop a lot of handguns.

[image: Micarta blocks]

Since you're looking beyond pure Micarta, you'll be happy to learn that a lot of composite materials have ballistic capabilities. For example, the [Micarta Shotblocker](https://www.professionalplastics.com/MICARTABRASS) line of panels can stop a wide range of handgun and rifle rounds (more details in [this PDF](http://www.norplex-micarta.asia/sites/default/files/docs/ShotBlocker%20Product%20Sheet.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

What you describe (paper impregnated with resin) was a thing in China, as tested by [Mythbusters](https://mythbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Paper_Armor_Myth)

> paper armor was in use as early as 600 BC and was built up from layers that may have been impregnated with resin or shellac. The Build Team tested several formulations for penetration resistance and found that a thick layer of folded paper, with no resin, gave the best results.
>
> Using an armor sample (1⁄2 in (13 mm) paper vs. 1⁄32 in (1 mm) steel) placed over a block of clay, they tested resistance to blunt force, swords, and arrows. The paper did as well as steel in the sword and arrow tests, failing only the blunt-force test, so the team built a full suit of paper armor to match against a period-accurate steel counterpart.
>
> Each team member ran one of three timed courses in both armor types to evaluate speed, endurance, and agility; paper outperformed steel in all three. Finally, they attacked the suits with arrows, swords, and two different firearms - an 18th-century flintlock pistol and a 19th-century .45 revolver. Both armor types resisted every attack except the .45, leading the team to classify the myth as plausible. They pointed out, though, that the paper armor could quickly begin to disintegrate if it got wet or took repeated blows (both of which happened during the full-scale tests).

Definitely possible, thus.